# How to disable formatOnSave only for the <template>, html, part of .vue file with Vetur and VSCode?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vuejs2

I'm having issues with getting correct formatting of the html in a .vue file in VScode and just want to disable it.

Is there any way to only disable it for the html part? Currently I've set `"editor.formatOnSave": false` and then use `"eslint.autoFixOnSave": true,` so it autoformats the js at least, but I'd like it to auto format the css (or in my case stylus) as well, *without* formatting the html.

I'm using Vetur & ESlint do do the formatting currently.

Comment: Maybe try a language-specific rule like "[html]": {
    "eslint.autoFixOnSave": false
  }